# Accuracy in outlier detection

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, outliers

I am having an issue understanding this question while learning about outliers. I have attached an image of the question. Is there anyone help me understanding the question as I am new to Data Mining and unable to crack this question. Resources for expanding my knowledge will be appreciated.

All I know right now is you can check the accuracy of one model for detecting an outlier by comparing the generated results and predicted ones. But in this problem, there is no such actual values which has led me towards the issue. It would be a great favor if anyone can help me out.
Thanks in advance[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwdlD.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the questions seems to be more related to the ROC curve interpretation than to the task at hand being an outlier prediction problem. It seems that it needs to understand how to compare two algorithms based on the ROC curve, and to conclude that the suitable metric to be used in this case is the AUC score.
Using Python and scikit-learn we can easily plot the two ROC curves like this:

```
#define three lists with the given data: two sets of scores and their true class
scores1 = [0.44, 0.94, 1.86, 2.15, 0.15, 0.5, 5.4, 3.09, 7.97, 5.21]
scores2 = [0.73, 0.18, 0.76, 1.6, 3.78, 4.45, 0.3, 3.3, 0.44, 9.94]
y = [0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0]

# calculate fpr, tpr and classification thresholds
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve, roc_auc_score, RocCurveDisplay
fpr1, tpr1, thresholds1 = roc_curve(y, scores1)
fpr2, tpr2, thresholds2 = roc_curve(y, scores2)
auc1 = roc_auc_score(y, scores1)
auc2 = roc_auc_score(y, scores2)

# get the curve displays using the above metrics
curve1 = RocCurveDisplay(fpr=fpr1, tpr=tpr1, roc_auc=auc1, 
estimator_name='Algo1')
curve2 = RocCurveDisplay(fpr=fpr2, tpr=tpr2, roc_auc=auc2, 
estimator_name='Algo2')
curve1.plot()
curve2.plot()
```

Then, from the plots you can interpret based on the values you can see for False Positive Rate on the x-axis vs True Positive Rate on the y-axis and the trade-off they imply. Moreover, you will see that the algorithm 1 having a graph that accounts for larger scores of TPR than those of the algorithm 2, is a better algorithm for this task. Moreover, this can be formalized using the AUC as a metric, which was calculated using "roc_auc_score".

Note that you can also have the plot manually if you calculate FPR and TPR for each of the algorithms using their corresponding classification thresholds.

Hope it helps :)

Regards,
Jehona.